# Accessing DOM by getElementById() in Vaadin 24 Lit component

Tags: vaadin24

I have a web component implemented with **Lit** and I need to invoke JS functions from a third party.
These JS functions use `document.getElementById()` to modify the DOM of the web component.
This instruction is not working because the inner elements of the web component are inside a shadow DOM.

I know I can access those elements from inside the web component using: `this.shadowRoot.getElementById()`.

But I need to use a third party JS library.
Is there a solution for this?